# Use Jest to test an API endpoint and its response

Tags: javascript, json, jestjs, fetch

I want to use jest to test an API endpoint to check if it returns a response and if the JSON contains the parameter keys that I need.

My function looks like the following:

```
export function getFiveDayWeatherByCoordinates(id) {
  let url = FORECAST_ID_URL(id);

  return fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      return data;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

}
```

It returns a JSON with a set of parameters, I will post only a snapshot:

```
{
cnt: 14,
cod: "200",
city: {
  coord: {lat: 38.7169, lon: -9.1333},
  country: "PT",
  id: 8012502,
  name: "Socorro",
  population: 0,
  timezone: 3600,
}
```

Every tutorial that I see until now says to mock the response, but I want to test the actual API.

Comment: do you want to test the api in server side itself? is it express?

Comment: I want to test the openweathermap API, it's not mine

Comment: what and why do you want to test then? also you cant test response, you can validate though.

Comment: Yes, I want to validate the response. I want to test the API response to see if it doesn't break my application. Since any response change would break the app.

Comment: for that you already have catch block. if you want to validate some parameters in response, you write your own basic javascript validations. you cannot use jest and all for this.

Comment: What should I use to test an API? Maybe Postman? Because I will not be accessing my app every day to check if it's still working.

Comment: you can use Jest for testing your react app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using [Frisby.js](https://www.frisbyjs.com/) to test the API responses. It's a great test framework for API testing that runs in Jest. I've used it numerous times to write API and backend integration tests. Although, I typically keep these test suites separate from my UI unit tests.

Here's an example:

```js
it('should return weather coords', async () => {
  return frisby
    .get(`${global.apiUrl}/my-weather-endpoint`)
    .expect('status', 200)
    .expect('jsonTypes', Joi.object({
      cnt: Joi.number().required(),
      cod: Joi.string().required(),
      city: Joi.object({
        coord: Joi.object({ 
          lat: Joi.number().required(),
          lon: Joi.number().required()
        }),
        country: Joi.string().required(),
        id: Joi.number().required(),
        name: Joi.string().required(),
        population: Joi.number().required(),
        timezone: Joi.number().required()
    }).required()
  });
});
```

Frisby also encourages the use of the [Joi](https://hapi.dev/family/joi) validation framework (it's already included in the npm package).

Comment: thanks for the advice, will have a look at Frisby.js, it looks to do what I need

Comment: you cant write a unit test for something that's your app does not include.

Comment: @AZ_ - It's not a unit test. It's more of an integration test. You can surely write a test that makes assertions about the response of an API, even if the API is not yours.

Comment: Glad it worked out @DiogoPeres. Good luck with your project.